# how to implement ngModel in select with user default value selected

Tags: angular

I have following HTML code:-

```html
    <form (ngSubmit)="searchTrain()">
        <div class="input-group">
            <select name="source" [(ngModel)]="source" required>
                <option [value]="" [selected]="true">-- source --</option>
                <option *ngFor="let src of sourceList" [value]="src">{{src}}</option>
            </select>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Find Trains</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and component:-

```js
    source = '';
    sourceList = ['Hyderabad', 'Bangalore', 'Ranchi', 'Patna', 'Delhi', 'Chennai', 'Mumbai', 'Pune', 'Kolkata', 'Jaipur'];

    searchTrain(){
        console.log(this.source);
    }
```

Here, I want

1. `-- source --` to be selected by default.
2. when I change the option I should get the selected option in the controller.

But it's not happening here.

I tried with `<select name="source" (ngModelChange)="source = $event" required>` in place of
`<select name="source" [(ngModel)]="source" required>` and the default option is selected successfully but then I am not able to get the selected option in controller when I submit the form.

How can both conditions be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [(ngModel)] you can add this code in it:

```
<select name="source" [(ngModel)]="defaultValue" required>
```

With a default value in component:

```
defaultValue = '-- source --';
```

A working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-default-for-select?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts